# Get public links to all files in folder from google cloud storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, google-cloud-storage

I'm running a static web page for a school project and need a way to load a large amount of images into a gallery without using PHP or making a very long HTML file.

I had an idea of using JavaScript to get the public links from all files in a google cloud storage folder and put them into an array. I could then loop through the array to add the images to the document. This way the page would be updated every time an image was added to the folder. I know this is really easy with PHP, but I can't run any server side languages with my setup. How do I get those public links into an array? I'm really new to JavaScript and the API documentation doesn't make a lot of sense to me. (I think I'm in over my head haha)

I also wonder if this is even worth doing from a performance standpoint? Would this just be too much to load? Do you have any other ideas on how I might be able to solve the problem?

Comment: This is a very broad question with no 'correct' answer. Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and post a new question.

Comment: go look at ajax requests. the google api probably returns json which should be easy to implement.